# How to see videos from a network stream(http)?

Tags: c++, c, http, video, youtube

I was wondering: how does youtube or any other website containing videos, send such data to clients?
When using the web browser, and asking for a webpage, what happens is that the browser sends an HTTP GET request to the server, which returns the html page; but how does the video data get transferred?
Is it opened an additional connection to do that?
And, is there a way to capture this stream in a program using some software library?

What i want to achieve is something like the VLC's network stream feature, which allows you to watch videos from youtube, but i don't know where to start from.

Thanks

Comment: You're asking how streaming video and computer networks work. One could write a book or ten on that. Far too broad a question for a Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube is primarily using [MPEG DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) for video streaming. If you click on any Youtube video with the right mouse button and select *stats for nerds* you will see it:

[image: screenshot]

HTTP based video streaming *protocols* like [MPEG DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP), [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming), [Smooth streaming](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming), etc. have a manifest file which describes how the actual video data is structured (there is information like URLs to each media chunk, available representations, information about the bitrate of each representation etc.). The client first downloads this manifest, parses it, and starts downloading the segments. After each download the client measures the channel throughput. And based on this information makes a decision which chunk to download in the next request.

Using [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) you can for example see which representations are available:

```
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6u9WJ01Oxs
```

Together with `curl` you can also download the DASH manifest (MPD)

```
curl $(youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbHSMwc4eCA --youtube-include-dash-manifest --dump-intermediate-pages -s | grep manifest.google | cut -d ' ' -f 5) > dash_manifest.mpd
```

After downloading the MPD you can play it for example with GPACs [Osmo4](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/) (MP4Client). Or maybe even VLC (I'm not sure if the DASH plugin in VLC was updated since 2012).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest protocol,
HTTP GET returns a video file with the proper mime type header.

As that's piracy prone and not really suitable for live streaming, some plugins use their own protocol, like `rtmp`, Or a protocol over HTTP, like `HLS`

To watch videos from youtube, you could check the [`youtube-dl`](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) project. Youtube is a moving target, so it requires lots of maintenance, and it's against their eula.